# How to pass a command as \uncover argument

Tags: beamer, fp

I can't pass a command to the argument of an uncover command in the beamer class. Why? How do I fix this? Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fp}
\newcommand{\fcEvalToInt}[1]{\FPeval{\fcResult}{clip(#1)}\fcResult}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A non-empty frame}
FcEvalToInt appears to work: $2+2=\fcEvalToInt{2+2 }$.

However inside an uncover command it doesn't: $1+1=\uncover<\fcEvalToInt{1+1}->{2}$. Why?
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[Edit:]@Suggestion to use \pause: the \pause functionality is by far not sufficient for my purposes.

Here's my most elementary use case, which I don't believe works with  \pause (or does it?).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\begin{array}{rcl}
\alert<2>{1+1}&\alert<2>{=}&\alert<2>{2}\\
\uncover<2->{\alert<2>{1+1} +1&\alert<0>{=}& \alert<2>{2}+1} \uncover<3->{=3}
\end{array}
\]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Let me explain more about my use case. Teaching is a lot about repetition, so imagine I want to use the computation above every time 1+1+1 appears. I could reproduce the code in the middle of a 30 phase slide, working out the slide numbers every time (this is what I do at the moment, takes hours). Alternatively, I could create a template which reproduces the above computation sequence relative to an input start frame. This is exactly what I aim to reproduce.

Comment: I think what you need is `$1+1=\uncover<2->{\fcEvalToInt{1+1}}$`.

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work is because the macro is non-expandable

Comment: You can use eTeX's `\numexpr` instead: `Inside an uncover command you can use $1+1=\uncover<\the\numexpr1+1\relax>{2}$.`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina's comment can get turned into an answer (it's technically correct) but I suspect there's a wider context here. Why  do you need to do arithmetic here? I suspect `beamer`'s flexible overlay numbering may help.

Comment: I am having 30+ phases in a slide. Adding a single phase in frames 1-5 means I have to shift the phases 6-30 one by one (causes hours of work). Is there a standard way to indicate a slide phase relative to another slide?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is just to find a robust way to add phases without having to shift manually the following ones, a simple solution is to use incremental specifications. For example, if you use `<+->` instead of `<number->` the `+`sign will be substituted by the current value of the counter `beamerpauses` and would shift automatically when inserting new phases.

Comment: That is not good: things are not uncovered consequentially. For example: 1+1=2 (phase 1) 1+1+1=2+1=3 (added in phase 2) phase 3 must highlight the first equation and a part of the second. So \pause is a no go here.

Comment: I think it is possible to do it with incremental specifications. I have tried with `\alert<.(2)>{1+1}&\alert<.(2)>{=}&\alert<.(2)>{2}\\ ` `\uncover<.(2)->{\alert<.(2)>{1+1}+1&\alert<0>{=}&\alert<+(1)>{2}+1}\uncover<.(2)->{=3}`and it does the same that your elementary case even if you insert a new stop before.

Comment: That sounds promising ... I am composing many slides these days so I will give it a try, if it works will mark this as a good answer.